# Python TkInter delete childs's grid

Tags: python-2.7, button, tkinter, grid, tkinter-canvas

How can I clear the grid into a canvas in Tkinter?

Actually i have this :

```
photoCanvas = Canvas(photoFrame,bg='#E5E7E9')
rowPhoto = 0
columnPhoto = 0
for i in range(0, len(listPhotos), 1):
     panel = Button(photoCanvas, image = listPhotos[i], borderwidth=0, height = 200, width = 200)
     panel.grid(row=rowPhoto, column=columnPhoto, padx=5, pady=5, sticky="nsew")
     if columnPhoto < 3:
         columnPhoto += 1
     else:
         rowPhoto += 1
         columnPhoto = 0
```

And i want to delete all my buttons.

Thx

Comment: Please post a [mcve]. What you've posted is way too minimal, doesn't run, doesn't create a grid, and the description is too vague.

Comment: I modify my post, sorry i don't speak english very well ...

Answer (score 0):

If you want to delete all widgets inside another widget -- such as all buttons in your canvas -- you can simply iterate over all of the children of the widget and call the `destroy` method.

For example:

```
for widget in photoCanvas.winfo_children():
    widget.destroy()
```

Comment: it's work but in GUI the elements stay visible, can i redraw or refresh my canvas ?

Comment: @Deakox: you will have to show code that illustrates that. When you do it properly, the elements go away. You don't need to refresh the canvas, that happens automatically.